# Unable to ping Beaglebone Black over Ethernet from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip, beagleboneblack

I just opened BBB from the box and its comes with installed OS in its eMMC card. I can read console output over serial connection. I connected my Ubuntu machine with BBB with Ethernet cable. Both are at same network but still unable to ping. The outpuf of ifconfig at BB side

```
root@beaglebone:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:84:e3:b8:ad:e3  
          inet6 addr: fe80::9a84:e3ff:feb8:ade3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:149 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:53 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:19926 (19.4 KiB)  TX bytes:12317 (12.0 KiB)
          Interrupt:40 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:157 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:157 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:16592 (16.2 KiB)  TX bytes:16592 (16.2 KiB)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:84:e3:b8:ad:e0  
          inet addr:192.168.7.2  Bcast:192.168.7.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

and the out at my Machine side

```
:~$ ifconfig
eno2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:f7:50:5c:4b:48  
          inet addr:192.168.7.5  Bcast:192.168.7.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4d23:a284:24c1:91b5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:68 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:7868 (7.8 KB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:ed400000-ed420000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:51440 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:51440 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3883601 (3.8 MB)  TX bytes:3883601 (3.8 MB)

wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:ea:56:39:3a:f5  
          inet addr:192.168.0.13  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5b15:c654:702d:eb71/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:140770 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22768 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:198511580 (198.5 MB)  TX bytes:4462728 (4.4 MB)
```

Does someone know why is it unable to ping ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to talk to your BBB over Ethernet and IPv4 then you will need to provide a DHCPv4 server on the LAN it connects to *or* configure a static IPv4 address. Just connecting your BBB to your Ubuntu machine via a direct cable will not work, as it requires further configuration on at least one or both sides.

One option is to connect both machines to a LAN that has a DHCPv4 server (in most cases a router). In your case only the BBB would need to be connected by Ethernet to it as your PC seems to already be connected to it by WiFi.

nb: IPv6 link-local is already possible:

- BBB address: `fe80::9a84:e3ff:feb8:ade3`
- PC address: `fe80::4d23:a284:24c1:91b5`

You can confirm this simply by:

- From the BBB: `ping6 fe80::9a84:e3ff:feb8:ade3%eth0`
- From the PC: `ping6 fe80::4d23:a284:24c1:91b5%eno2`

Not all software handles link-local addresses and the required interface identifier well though. Web browsers most prominently don't.